# PHP 7.4 | property is not being setted

Tags: php

```
<?php 
    class Adress {
        private string $_Street;
        private string $_Neighborhood;
        private string $_Landmark;
        private int $_HomeNumber;

        public function __construct (string $str, string $nei, int $hom, string $lan) {
            $this -> setAdress($str, $nei, $hom, $lan);
        }

        private function setAdress(string $str, string $nei, int $hom, string $lan) {
            $this -> $_Street = $str;
            $this -> $_Neighborhood = $nei;
            $this -> $_HomeNumber = $hom;
            $this -> $_Landmark = $lan;                  
        }

        public function __toString() {
            return
            "Street: {$this -> $_Street},\nNeighborhood: {$this -> $_Neighborhood},\nLandmark: {$this -> $_Landmark},\nHome Number: {$this -> $_HomeNumber}.";
        }
    }

    $House = new Adress("Presbitero Porfirio Gomes da Silva", "Capim Macio", 102, "Ceva");
    echo $House;
?>
```

I'm new in PHP, why are `$this -> $_Street`, `$this -> $_Neighborhood`, `$this -> $_HomeNumber` equal to `$this -> $_Landmark` ?

I can't understand why it's happening, I need someone to explain it to me.
You need to run the code to understand my question.

Comment: Access properties in PHP without the `$`. For example `$this-> _Street = $str;`.. If you had turned on `error_reporting(E_ALL);` then you'd get the undefined variable warning

Answer (score 0):

You're using wrong syntax to assign values to variables and then reading them.

Try this code:

```
<?php 
class Adress {
    private string $_Street;
    private string $_Neighborhood;
    private string $_Landmark;
    private int $_HomeNumber;

    public function __construct (string $str, string $nei, int $hom, string $lan) {
        $this -> setAdress($str, $nei, $hom, $lan);
    }

    private function setAdress(string $str, string $nei, int $hom, string $lan) {
        $this->_Street = $str;
        $this->_Neighborhood = $nei;
        $this->_HomeNumber = $hom;
        $this->_Landmark = $lan;                  
    }

    public function __toString() {
        return
        "Street: {$this->_Street},\nNeighborhood: {$this->_Neighborhood},\nLandmark: {$this->_Landmark},\nHome Number: {$this->_HomeNumber}.";
    }
}

$House = new Adress("Presbitero Porfirio Gomes da Silva", "Capim Macio", 102, "Ceva");
echo $House;
?>
```

Also you should replace all `\n` with `<br>` for next line in browser.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
    class Adress {
        private  $_Street;
        private $_Neighborhood;
        private $_Landmark;
        private $_HomeNumber;

        public function __construct($str, $nei, $hom, $lan) {
            $this->$_Street = $str;
            $this->$_Neighborhood = $nei;
            $this->$_HomeNumber = $hom;
            $this->$_Landmark = $lan;
        }
        public function toString() {
            return 'Street: '.$this->$_Street.'."\n".
'Neighborhood:'.$this->$_Neighborhood.'."\n".
'Landmark: '.$this->$_Landmark.'."\n".
'Home Number: '.$this->$_HomeNumber;
        }
    }
    $House = new Adress("Presbitero Porfirio Gomes da Silva", "Capim Macio", 102, "Ceva");
    echo $House->toString();
?>
```